# Как изменить порт для процесса?

Tags: java, linux, fedora, wildfly, jboss

ОС - федора 29. Установил сервер wildfly при запуске приложения () в ИДЕ падает такая ошибка -  'JBoss 17.0.0.Final': Address 127.0.0.1:9090 is already in use.
Как я пытался ее решить!? 
Нашел процесс который использует порт 9090,8080 и убил его средствами из коробки.И все заработало Но до первой перезагрузки! Каждый раз убивать процесс это дич.
Как процессу поменять порт? Или как это решить может другими путями?Спасибо!
На всякий случай файл standalone.xml

```
 <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
<socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9090}"/>
<socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
<socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
<socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
<socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
<socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
<socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
<outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
<remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
</outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9090}"/>
```

Тут пробовал поменять?

Comment: Конечно, при изменении на другой порт, и перезагрузки сервера, выбранный новый порт будет так-же занят!(

Comment: а может быть ваша программа уже запустилась в автозапуске или как служба?

Comment: Как проверить это?
Сервер да стартует автоматически при запуске. При его отключении и если  начать разворачивать приложение то перваначальной ошибки нет, но есть другая, решение которой у меня нагуглить не выходит!
org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: WFLYCTL0081: Failed to back up /opt/wildfly-17.0.0.Final/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: WFLYCTL0081: Failed to back up /opt/wildfly-17.0.0.Final/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml

Comment: Спасибо, вы дали мне наводку на решение этого вопроса!)

Answer (score 1):

1. Я выключил из автозагрузки сервер.
2. Дал права на все файлы.

Comment: Я так понял, что это ответ -- судя по комментариям, а галку вы оставили на ответе участника, который вам помог больше всего, натолкнув на решение, верно? Если да -- то стоит как-то более явно написать в ответе, что это ответ, а то это не сразу становится понятно. Вдруг кому-то ещё пригодится.

Comment: Какой был вопрос - такой и ответ) хорошо что уточнили что именно происходит у Вас. Оказывается порт менять не нужно.